# How to change screen resolution in the linux zoom tool

Tags: system-settings, reset

I have an Asus laptop running Linux, and I let one of my younger siblings go on it. He went into the settings and turned on the zoom tool, but increased the screen brightness so it's completely white. Now I can't see anything on my screen and have no way to change it. How can I fix this?

Comment: hi... are you at system now